# In FireFox uBlock Origin, how can I block anything after a forward slash?

Tags: firefox

I want to use uBlock Origin to block anything after SUBJECT in this example URL:
https://newsela.com/subject/other/2000265525

So for example, if the digits "2000265525" or "other" in the URL changes to anything, it is blocked.

How do I achieve this?

In My filters, I tried adding this but had no luck:
newsela.com/subject/*

Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding two pipes should do the trick:

`||newsela.com/subject/*`